# CommonJS and Jest Mocking - Exported Function not being mocked

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, commonjs

I'm having trouble mocking specific functions within my modules using commonjs

example module `db.js`

```
function createDefaultProfile(user_id) {
 return { version: 1, username: user_id };
}

function updateOrCreateProfile(user_id, profile) {
  if (profile && profile.credential_id) return null; //no need to update
  if (!profile) profile = createDefaultProfile(user_id);
  if (!profile.credential_id) {
    //update profile with key
  }

module.exports = {createDefaultProfile, updateOrCreateProfile }
```

example test file try 1:

```
describe("updateOrCreateUser()", () => {
  const db = require('../db.js')

  it("should call createDefaultProfile() when no profile is provided", () => {
    db.createDefaultProfile = jest.fn()
    db.updateOrCreateProfile(userID)
    expect(db.createDefaultProfile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

example test file try 2:

```
describe("updateOrCreateUser()", () => {
  jest.mock('../db', () => {
    // Require the original module to not be mocked...
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../db');

    return {
      __esModule: true, // Use it when dealing with esModules
      ...originalModule,
      createDefaultProfile: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('arbitrary value'),
    }
  })

  const db = require('../db.js')

  it("should call createDefaultProfile() when no profile is provided", () => {
    db.updateOrCreateProfile(userID)
    expect(db.createDefaultProfile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

both return the wrong values as the mocked module never gets called..
in both instances it seems as if the scope of the mocked module is not correct...

Answer (score 0):

The `createDefaultProfile` function called within `updateOrCreateProfile` function is original, NOT the mocked one you try to replace with `jest.fn()`. Try below:

`db.js`:

```js
function createDefaultProfile(user_id) {
  return { version: 1, username: user_id };
}

function updateOrCreateProfile(user_id, profile) {
  if (profile && profile.credential_id) return null;
  if (!profile) profile = exports.createDefaultProfile(user_id);
  if (!profile.credential_id) {
    console.log('update profile with key');
  }
}

exports.createDefaultProfile = createDefaultProfile;
exports.updateOrCreateProfile = updateOrCreateProfile;
```

`db.test.js`:

```js
describe('63118259', () => {
  describe('updateOrCreateUser', () => {
    const db = require('./db.js');
    it('should call createDefaultProfile() when no profile is provided', () => {
      const userID = 1;
      const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
      db.createDefaultProfile = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ credential_id: null });
      db.updateOrCreateProfile(userID);
      expect(db.createDefaultProfile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('update profile with key');
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/63118259/db.test.js (10.819s)
  63118259
    updateOrCreateUser
      ✓ should call createDefaultProfile() when no profile is provided (26ms)

  console.log
    update profile with key

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   77.78 |       50 |      50 |   85.71 |                   
 db.js    |   77.78 |       50 |      50 |   85.71 | 2                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.367s
```

Comment: still not working for me locally. this is leaning towards possibility that my installation of jest isn't working properly.